# Can running a CPU intensive task in a Low priority process disrupt my user experience?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu

I'd like to run the [bitcoin](http://bitcoin.org/) client to generate me some coins, and I notice that it's taking 100% CPU, so I lowered it to Low priority.

Should my user experience (for other programs) be affected by having this program running at low priority?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be somewhat, because the system won't react instantly to other cpu requests. Depending on how many processors your machine has, it may not be noticeable.

Comment: I have a duel core machine. If I limit bitcoin to run only on one core, then this should hardly be noticable if at all, right? (bitcoin's settings can limit the number of cores it's running on)

Answer (score 2):

If you are speaking specifically about bitcoin, you won't generate a high enough hash rate using your cpu. The only way to really make bitcoins is using an ATI GPU. The hash rate on CPUs is so low that you will bog down your computer for essentially nothing. If you are serious about mining bitcoins, you need an ATI GPU. I put a beginners guide together at http://startbitcoin.com

Comment: Yeah, I realized that a long time ago. I'll leave mining to miners, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

When a process is at the lowest priority ("low" in Task Manager, "idle" elsewhere), it will still use as much CPU as it needs (even 100%), but *only if no other programs need it*. (This includes GUI operations too.) In other words, Bitcoin should not have any performance impact on processes running at "Normal" priority.